# Minimum buffer length to read a float

Tags: c, buffer, fgets

I'm writing a small command-line program that reads two floats, an int, and a small string (4 chars max) from stdin. I'm trying to figure out the buffer size I should create and pass to fgets. I figured I could calculate this based on how many digits should be included in the maximum values of `float` and `int` respectively, like so:

```
#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>

...

int fmax = log10(FLOAT_MAX) + 2;     // Digits plus - and .
int imax = log10(INT_MAX) + 1;       // Digits plus -
int buflen = 4 + 2*fmax + imax + 4;  // 4 chars, 2 floats, 1 int, 3 spaces and \n

...

fgets(inbuf, buflen + 1, stdin);
```

But it's occurred to me that this might not actually be correct. `imax` ends up being 10 on my system, which seems a bit low, while `fmax` if 40. (Which I'm thinking is a bit high, given that longer values may be represented with e notation.)

So my question is: is this the best way to work this out? Is this even necessary? It just feels more elegant than assigning a buffer of 256 and assuming it'll be enough. Call it a matter of pride ;P.

Comment: Please choose between C and C++ when asking your question. The answers will be different, according to which language you use.

Comment: Why would you want to use different buffers for the int and the floats? You'll have to read them one after the other anyway, so take a buffer big enough to hold the float and be done with it.

Comment: Also: Take a look at INT_MAX and see that it really only has ten digits or so in base-10 representation. Then think about double (64 bit, with 53 Bit mantissa) and you'll probably see that 40 digits sounds about right.

Comment: If 1 GB is worth $10, each byte is worth 0.000001 cents. If minimum wage is $6 per hour or 0.001667 cents per second. The point at which your time is worth more than the memory you are saving is about 0.6 ms per byte. Put another way, if you are not saving 1.5 KB **per second** you could be wasting your time. If by saving a few bytes, you introduce a bug, this could cost you far more. Memory is re-usable, your time is not. ;)

Comment: @Peter you are forgetting about the OCD factor though :)

Comment: @Jeremy, I agree, its hard to write "wasteful" code. At some point, you have to realise its an academic exercise.

Comment: Rob: Sorry, fixed. I figured the answer would be the same for both languages, though obviously C++ has more/different tools at its disposal.
arne: I'm using a float not a double, but fair point.
Peter: Jeremy's right (or wrong... but right ;P), though I'm very interested in embedded programming... hence, being a memory miser :P.

Comment: @Daniel: Please use `@user` notification syntax.

Comment: @Tomalak It wouldn't allow me to tag multiple users, and I didn't want to play favourites. Should I split things like that into multiple comments in the future?

Comment: @Daniel: I think so yes. Much better than writing comments that nobody will get notified about. (Protip: you can circumvent the silly notification limit by using at least one \` in your comment :D)

Comment: @Peter: Your analysis is flawed. If there are a billion devices running your code, each byte saved is saved on every such device, meaning each byte saved is worth $1000. That's pretty big. :-)

Comment: @R.. The analysis is only to give a sense of proportion. However, you appear to be using my argument to find the point at which it matters. Of course memory on some devices cost much more than others esp. if you can't upgrade them because they are not yours. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type of thing is a place where I would actually use `fscanf` rather than reading into a fixed-size buffer first. If you need to make sure you don't skip a newline or other meaningful whitespace, you can use `fgetc` to process character-by-character until you get the the beginning of the number, then `ungetc` before calling `fscanf`.

If you want to be lazy though, just pick a big number like 1000...

Answer (score 2):

This is defined for base 10 floating point numbers (`#include <float.h>` or the equivalent member of `std::numeric_limits<float_type>`):

```
FLT_MAX_10_EXP // for float
DBL_MAX_10_EXP // for double
LDBL_MAX_10_EXP // for long double
```

As is the maximum precision for decimals in base 10:

```
FLT_DIG // for float
DBL_DIG // for double
LDBL_DIG  // for long double
```

Although it really depends on what you define to be a valid floating point number. You could imagine someone expecting:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00000000000000000000
```

to be read in as zero.

Comment: Fair point. I never really imagined that I could account for every technically correct input, though I guess it's best to account for as many reasonable inputs as possible, which skimping on the buffer size may cut out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a good way to determine the maximum length of a float string algorithmically, but what fun is that?  Let's figure it out by brute force!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int, char **)
{
   float f;
   unsigned int i = -1;
   if (sizeof(f) != sizeof(i))
   {
      printf("Oops, wrong size!  Change i to a long or whatnot so the sizes match.\n");
      return 0;
   }
   printf("sizeof(float)=%li\n", sizeof(float));

   char maxBuf[256] = "";
   int maxChars = 0;
   while(i != 0)
   {
      char buf[256];
      memcpy(&f, &i, sizeof(f));
      sprintf(buf, "%f", f);
      if ((i%1000000)==0) printf("Calclating @ %u: buf=[%s] maxChars=%i (maxBuf=[%s])\n", i, buf, maxChars, maxBuf);
      int numChars = strlen(buf);
      if (numChars > maxChars)
      {
         maxChars = numChars;
         strcpy(maxBuf, buf);
      }
      i--;
   }
   printf("Max string length was [%s] at %i chars!\n", maxBuf, maxChars);
}
```

Looks like the answer might be 47 characters per float (at least on my machine), but I'm not going to let it run to completion so it's possibly more.

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer from @MSN, you can't really know your buffer is large enough.

Consider:

```
const int size = 4096;
char buf[size] = "1.";
buf[size -1 ] = '\0';
for(int i = 2; i != size - 1; ++i)
    buf[i] = '0';
double val = atof(buf);
std::cout << buf << std::endl;
std::cout << val << std::endl;
```

Here `atof()` handles (as it is supposed to), a thousand character representation of `1`.

So really, you can do one or more of:

- Handle the case of not having a large enough buffer
- Have better control over the input file
- Use `fscanf` directly, to make the buffer size someone else's problem